# File or directory not found. The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, iis

I have developed a project with laravel  php framework. It's working perfectly on my localhost where xampp is running. I have uploaded my whole project in the "wwwroot" folder and I can only get my opening page. But when I try to click on any link I get:

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable..

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: That doesn't look like it's what the [complete .htaccess](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/10.x/public/.htaccess) should look like. If this is a shared server with everything in `wwwroot`, then you'll have to do some tweaking since Laravel should be serving out of the `public` folder

Comment: double check that the mod_rewrite module is actually enabled. And your site configuration allows htaccess overrides and that you are indeed using apache because other webservers do not support htaccess. You tagged this IIS which is a completely different configuration to get it to work if that is indeed what you are using

Comment: Some hosters also require you to set `RewriteBase /`

Comment: The code snippet you provided is used to configure the mod_rewrite module on the Apache HTTP server, but your case is tagged with IIS. So is your project deployed on IIS or Apache?

Comment: If you are using IIS, URL rewriting is usually handled through the web.config file. Please make sure that the URL Rewrite module is installed and enabled in the IIS server. Please refer to this link to learn how to create rewrite rules for the URL rewrite module. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module If you are still experiencing problems, check the IIS logs for more detailed error information.